WebStorm Beta Terminal Split view switches context windows after each executed command
I have tried this both on my Windows 11 machine and my MacBook Pro. Is there a setting that I am not seeing that will turn this off?
It's a strange "feature" to opt into by default, I'd expect that the focus would remain in the terminal of the most recent command execution.
Any direction would be greatly appreciated.
There wasn't much to try, looking through settings and searching the internet for this issue has been fruitless.
